# How many bits are in a qubit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information

How many bits of information can be stored in a qubit? On making a measurement on a qubit, one can catch it in either $|0\rangle$ or $| 1\rangle$. Seems that measurement on a qubit can not reveal more than a single bit. But does it mean the a qubit can't store more than 1 bit of information?

Answer (score 23):

No more than one. It follows from [Holevo's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holevo%27s_theorem) that $n$ qubits cannot be used to store more than $n$ bits of information.
See for example [these notes](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/quantum15/lecture18.pdf) for an explanation of Holevo's theorem (interestingly, the main question answered by these notes is *exactly* the title of this question).

Very roughly speaking, the reason for this is that if you try to encode $n$ bits of information in a system of dimension $d<2^n$ (so, for example, in less than $n$ qubits), then there is no reliable way to *retrieve* such information. This is because if $d<2^n$, then there are too few orthogonal states on which to store the information (if two states are not orthogonal, they cannot be deterministically distinguished).

Note that this is very different than saying that a single qubit requires a single bit to be described. In fact, in general, you need an infinite amount of bits to describe the state of a single qubit, because a single qubit is characterised by *continuous* numbers.
This means that, in some sense, a single qubit can *encode* an arbitrarily large amount of information.
The problem is that you can't deterministically *decode* such information afterwards, using a single copy of said qubit. You *could* use many copies of the same qubits to completely reconstruct its state, and therefore recover all of the information encoded in it, but this turns out to be a pretty inefficient information storage scheme.

Comment: Great answer. There should probably be some mention superdense coding, too. Superdense coding does not strictly pack more than n bits of information into 
 n qubits, but it is a predictable source of confusion on the subject. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superdense_coding
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412558/quantum-superdense-coding-how-many-qubits-are-needed?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Your answer has really been quite helpful. I was struggling in getting this. I just want to know one thing. Why do we need infinite bits to store the state of a qubit? And on measuring the qubit, we get one bit of information ( either 0 or 1 depending on the collapsed state). How can we construct the state of the qubit by repeated measurement when in effect we would be getting 0 or 1 again and again?

Comment: What do you mean by qubit sare characterised by continuous numbers?

Comment: @Shashaank you can open new threads to ask separate questions

Comment: @Shashaank We need infinite bits to store the state of a qubit because the state of a qubit is a superposition of the state 0 and 1, which can be described as a weighted sum of the two states. The weights determine the phases and amplitudes of the qubit which determine the probability of observing the outcome 0 and 1 states. Because the weights have continuous values, we need infinite bits to encode them exactly, e.g., 0.14159265...

Comment: @Shashaank We can reconstruct the *approximate* state of the qubit by repeated measurements because we can construct the measurements so that we can measure the probability of observing 0 and 1 states of equivalent qubits, from which we can estimate the approximate values of the weights and thus reconstruct the superposition state of the qubit. The estimate values are just approximate and the procedure is costly, thus, currently it is inefficient to use this scheme to store information as pointed out by gIS.

Comment: Great answer. We can store and retrieve only n bits using n qubits. The common ambiguity may come from a subtle point in storing capacity vs. processing capacity of qubit. Roughly speaking, because n qubits can encode the superposition of all $2^n$ states at the same time, there may be some conceivable methods to let all $2^n$ states be processed at the same time. So the output is still n bits, but the processing capacity is much larger. I think this is the main advantage of quantum computing vs. classical computing, and also one of the main focuses of current quantum computing research.

Answer (score 3):

What is really contained in a single qubit are 2 real numbers. This is the amplitude of the $|1\rangle$ state (the other one is given by the normalization), and the relative phase of the two states. When measured, we get out a single bit of information, as you correctly stated, but with which probability we get this specific bit is determined by these real numbers. Measuring equivilantly prepared states multiple times allows us to infer something about the 2 variables contained in the state.

Comment: What do you mean by equivalently prepared states? It is impossible to have two copies of a qubit by the no-cloning theorem right?

Comment: The no cloning theorem only states there cannot be a device which takes an arbitrary state as input and outputs two copies of that state. Nothing prevents us from just running a quantum circuit more than once.

Comment: Hmm, i don't get it fully. How would you prepare equivalent states? Btw i should add that I'm not from a physics background so i only know some elementary stuff mathematically.

Comment: Then have a look at how we prepare quantum states in the first place. I am talking about just doing that twice. Say, you have a very easy circuit: initialize to $|0\rangle$, apply a y-rotation gate by some angle and measure in the z-basis. Record your findings and do the experiment again. By the statistical distribution of many outcomes you can determine the amplitude of the 1 and the 0 state after that circuit. This is exaclty what the other answer is talking about. You need to run your whole setup multiple times, so you cannot (in one shot) extract more than one bit of information.

Comment: Ok i guess i have to do a little more research on that. It seems to me that someone already has to know what the amplitudes will be in order to make the machine you described in which case they already have complete information about the quantum state but another person will have to measure the state and find out the amplitudes statistically. I guess the first person could make a ton of those states and the second person will measure them. Anyway thanks a lot for giving me a direction to keep thinking.